# How to append data to splayed table

Tags: kdb

I have a splayed table with a folder structure

```
myroot/
    2023.01.01
        mytable
            col1
            col2
            ...
            .d                
    2023.01.02
        ...
    ...
    sym
```

looking at the documentation of upsert

```
x upsert y
```

Overwrite or append records to a table
where x is a table, or the name of a table as a symbol atom, or the name of a splayed table as a directory handle

However it appears to expect `sym` and `.d` to be on the folder the file handle points to, but they are in different folders.

How can I append the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sym file `sym` (for enumeration) and column order file `.d` should never be in the same folder, kdb+ won't expect this.

You should be able append to a table in your database by using `.Q.en` to enumerate the data, assuming the database has been loaded first and the data you are trying to append is a table.

```
/ load database
\l myroot

/ enumerate data and upsert
`:2023.01.01/mytable/ upsert .Q.en[`sym]data
```

If the data to append is in the format of list of records to insert then the following should work (provided the correct schema is used):

```
`:2023.01.01/mytable/ upsert (`sym?`XYZ;.z.p;0.1;0.1;1;1)
```

Alternatively if you can't or don't wish to load the entire database you just need to bring the `sym` file in to memory before enumerating and appending.

```
sym:get[`:myroot/sym]
```

Comment: Best to always leave a trailing `/` so that if the table does not exist it will be created a as a splay and not a flat file.

Comment: Cheers, you are totally right on that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. when trying this, I get an error
evaluation error:

sym.sym

  [1]  (.Q.enxs)

I cant find any documentation on this, and the sym file itself seems to be good

Comment: I am unfamiliar with that error. Do the permissions on the sym file allow for modifications?

Comment: yes, permissions are ok. I can also load the existing data, append the new data and then write the combination as splayed table. but I wanted to avoid loading the data so your approach with loading the sym file was what I was looking for